# I can't install Composer

Tags: composer-php

Error when I try for install Composer.

> The `https://getcomposer.org/versions` file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu.

Can someone help me?
[image: error composer]

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you did and how you did it. Just "when I try to install Composer" is not much to work with.

Comment: @Peh u can see the picture of error bc i can't provide some more information i'm blocked of the first !thanx

Comment: Just an FYI the error is "An attempt to connect failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a certain time or an established connection failed because the connection host did not respond"

Comment: This looks like your internet connection or Composers server were down. Did you try it again some time later?

Comment: @AndyHolmes where i can check that error and corrected that ?

Comment: As @Peh says it looks like the network dropped, try again later on

Comment: To begin with... Can you load [https://getcomposer.org/versions](https://getcomposer.org/versions) in your browser?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i have that in my browser :{
    "stable": [{"path": "/download/1.3.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.3.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "preview": [{"path": "/download/1.3.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.3.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "snapshot": [{"path": "/composer.phar", "version": "b3fe9fa1a5cac1c33009f4668933e43b737fb8db", "min-php": 50300}]
}

Comment: And the installer does still not work?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes same problem !

Comment: Do you use a proxy?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no i don't use any proxy!

Comment: @Peh always same problem i try without result ...!

Comment: @AndyHolmes always same problem i try without result ...!

Comment: I suspect there's something in your network configuration that prevents it from working in elevated processes. You'll probably have to skip Windows installer and use any of the other installation methods.